# Reasons for a PL/SQL function to get slower with every execution

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql

I created a PL/SQL function that translates sdo_geometry to ESRI sde.st_geometry:

```
create or replace
function tostgeom(sdogeom in sdo_geometry)
  return sde.ST_GEOMETRY
  is
  BEGIN
    return  SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_OPERATORS.st_geomfromwkb_f(sdo_geometry.get_wkb(sdogeom), 25832);
    EXCEPTION 
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            return null;
  END;
```

I need this function because some geometries are "broken" and can't be translated to st_geometry. (Testing the sdo_geometry with sdo_util functions reveals no problem)

Then I call this function in SQL:

```
create table test as 
select id,tostgeom(GEOMETRIE) as geometrie from my_polygons
where rownum<8000;
```

The results are as expected, but the execution time gets slower (relatively) the more rows I include via "rownum".

For example:

- 1000 rows take 1.7 seconds
- 2000 rows take 3.6 seconds
- 4000 rows take 7.5 seconds
- 8000 rows take 17.5 seconds

As you can see, the execution "time per row" gets gradually slower for more rows.
If I use it on the full ~2 millon rows, it never finishes.

What could be the problem here?

I would expect the time per row to get better instead of worse for bigger datasets, beause of lesser overhead?!?

Thanks for any thoughts!

**EDIT:**

I made some more tests and it seems the problem is entirely within the "sdo_geometry.get_wkb" function.
When I use only this function to create a new table with a wkb-blob-column I get this results:

Objects | to_wkb (seconds) | objects/sec

- 10000 | 13 | 0,0013
- 20000 | 31 | 0,0016
- 30000 | 54 | 0,0018
- 60000 | 145 | 0,0024

The performance is obviously degrading the more rows are to be processed.

Is that a case for Oracel support?

**Edit 2:**

I looked at the v$mystat values for 10k, 60k and 120k rows.
[image]

- Init: Initial Values for the statistics
- diff: Difference after processiong of 10k rows
- diff2: Difference after processiong of 60k rows
- factor2: quotient diff2/diff
- diff3: Difference after processiong of 120k rows
- factor3: quotient diff3/diff

I only displayed the statistics where the factor ist greater than anticipated. (I assumed that the factor should not be greater than the increase in rows. 10k->60k Factor should be maximum 6)

Any Idea what those stats indicate?

Comment: Do you need to do this once? or frequently? if it is once, you can create an empty table, use dbms_parallel_execute to fire off parallel threads, each to process n rows at a time which will insert into new table and commit. If you plan on doing this frequently, you might want to check your resource consumption by taking snapshot of v$mystat  between runs for 1000/2000/4000/8000 rows and compare to see where it is increasing. Perhaps you could share it with us here to get some clues. Right now there isn't much to go on here.

Comment: I would be happy if it worked once. But in the long run, I will need to do it more often. I asked the DBA to perform the tests with "v$mystat" since apparently you need "sys" to use it. But I could narrow down the problem a bit. See Edit.

Comment: V$MYSTAT is usually a public synonym and if a select is missing as your DBA. No harm there. And your dba is incorrect, you don't need SYS to use it as long as privs are granted. Get those privs then use something like runstats (do a google search) to compare. If you are in a hurry, oracle support is a good choice then.

Comment: I got the v$mystat privs now. See edit please. I also tried dbms_parallel_execute, but I can't get it to work since it always complains about "missing physical rowids".

Comment: I think you should open a case with Oracle support.